# How to remove active classList of first click when clicked the 2nd one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I want to remove the first clicked toggle class when clicked the 2nd one**

```
let counter = 0;
inputOptions.forEach(inputOptions => {

    inputOptions.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

        inputOptions.classList.toggle('active');

        if (inputOptions.innerHTML == "Dhaka") {
            counter++;
        } else { counter = 0; }**strong text**

    })
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It's not clear.

Comment: I mean to say there are four options. when I clicked the first option its selected and colored green. But when I clicked the 2nd option the first option remains selected. how to remove it?

Comment: Can you provider more of the code? The best would be some codepen or so

Comment: https://codepen.io/johnny64/pen/LYbVyBg

Comment: you only wnat to have one button green at a time, right ? If you click one button, it should turn green, and all previously clicked buttons should turn back to default color , correct ?

Comment: Yes @PascalLamers

Answer (score 0):

You need to list out previous clicked button like below:

`const activeButton = document.querySelector(".active");`

Then `remove` class name `active` of that previously clicked button:

```
if (activeButton)   
  activeButton.classList.remove('active');
```

Here is the code:

```
 inputOptions.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  const activeButton = document.querySelector(".active");

  if (activeButton) {
    activeButton.classList.remove('active'); 
} 
  inputOptions.classList.toggle('active');

  if (inputOptions.innerHTML == "Dhaka") {
     counter++;
  } 
  else { counter = 0; }
  });
```